# Как установить английский язык speech.Synthesis

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть следующий код:

```
const getVoices = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices()
    if (voices.length) {
      resolve(voices)
      return
    }
    speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => {
      voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices()
      resolve(voices)
    }
  })
}

const printVoicesList = async () => {
;(await getVoices()).forEach(voice => {
console.log(voice.name, voice.lang)
})
}

printVoicesList();
```

Он выводит список всех голосов, которые доступны в текущем браузере. В хроме все работает отлично. Но вот на андроиде в браузерах или в опере(на компе) выводится только 2 языка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне нужен только англ. язык для озвучки, как мне установить для всех платформ и браузеров стандартный язык - английский.
Неужели опера поддерживает только рус. язык, этого же не может быть.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам столкнулась с тем, что не все браузеры поддерживают голоса. У оперы всего 2 шт. и оба русские. Привожу пример кода как можно получить голоса в select или посмотреть в консоли. У разных браузеров по разному у Microsoft Edge их больше всего.

```
<body>
    <form class="row">
        <div class="col-3 text-primary h5">
            Выберите голос
        </div>

        <div class="col-9">
            <select name="sel" id="voices" class="form-select"></select>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    const speechSynthesis = window.speechSynthesis;
    const voiceSelect = document.getElementById('voices');
    // голоса
    const LANG_EN = 'en-GB';
    const LANG_RU = 'ru-RU';

    let voices = [];

    const populateVoiceList = () => {

        voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();

// тут только английские
        const voiceList = voices
        .map((voice, index) => voice.lang === LANG_EN && `<option value=${index}>${voice.name} (${voice.lang})</option>`)
        .join('');
// тут все голоса
        // const voiceList = voices
        // .map((voice, index) => `<option value=${index}>${voice.name} (${voice.lang})</option>`)
        // .join('');

    // В консоли можем посмотреть все наши голоса
    console.log(voices);

        voiceSelect.innerHTML = voiceList;
    };

    // Строчки отображаем наши голоса
    populateVoiceList();
    speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', populateVoiceList);
    </script>
</body>
```